# Visual Studio code breakpoint set to hollow grey circle and not working. error(unbound breakpoint)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I set breakpoint on type script code.Break point become hollow grey circle and when hover over it, it show unbound breakpoint.

/home/varsha/Downloads/IMG_20211118_174233.jpg

My launch.json is as below:-

```
"version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "pwa-node"
    },
    {
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/index.js",
        "restart": true,
    
        "console":"integratedTerminal",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
         ]
      }
   ]
```

}

And my "tasks.json" is as below:-

```
  {
    "version": "2.0.0",
      "tasks": [
       {
         "type": "typescript",
         "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
         "option": "watch",
         "problemMatcher": [
             "$tsc-watch"
         ],
         "group": {
             "kind": "build",
             "isDefault": true
         },
          "label": "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
     }
 ]
```

}